# How to center title and section page in plain frame of Beamer Berkeley

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, sectioning

I am using Beamer Berkeley theme with a broader sidebar. I want to center the information in the title page and also in the section pages horizontally.

To achieve that, I use the plain option for the frame. However, it seems that the position of the title etc. and the section name are relative to the sidebar, although the sidebar itself is hidden due to the plain mode. How can I fulfill the requirement? Thank you.

The MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[width=2cm]{Berkeley}

\AtBeginSection[]{
\begin{frame}[plain]
\vfill
\centering
\begin{beamercolorbox}            
[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
\usebeamerfont{title}\thesection. \insertsectionhead\par%
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vfill
\end{frame}
}

\title{Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title}
\author{Author Author Author}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
Frame 1
\end{frame}

\section{Section Section Section Section Section}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
Frame 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 3}
Frame 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the title and section pages half the sidebar width to the left:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[width=2cm]{Berkeley}

\AtBeginSection[]{
{
\hoffset=-.5\beamersidebarwidth
\begin{frame}[plain]
\vfill
\centering
\begin{beamercolorbox}            
[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
\usebeamerfont{title}\thesection. \insertsectionhead\par%
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vfill
\end{frame}
}
}

\title{Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title}
\author{Author Author Author}

\begin{document}

{
\hoffset=-.5\beamersidebarwidth
\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
Frame 1
\end{frame}

\section{Section Section Section Section Section}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
Frame 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 3}
Frame 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you would like to have more space on the title and section pages, you could move the title left by the full width of the sidebar and increase the text width:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[width=2cm]{Berkeley}

\AtBeginSection[]{
{
\hoffset=-\beamersidebarwidth
\advance\textwidth\beamersidebarwidth
\hsize\textwidth 
\columnwidth\textwidth
\begin{frame}[plain]
\vfill
\centering
\begin{beamercolorbox}            
[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
\usebeamerfont{title}\thesection. \insertsectionhead\par%
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vfill
\end{frame}
}
}

\title{Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title}
\author{Author Author Author}

\begin{document}

{
\hoffset=-\beamersidebarwidth
\advance\textwidth\beamersidebarwidth
\hsize\textwidth 
\columnwidth\textwidth
\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
Frame 1
\end{frame}

\section{Section Section Section Section Section}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
Frame 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 3}
Frame 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]