# Beamer Berkeley: remove frame number in title and section pages

Tags: beamer, sectioning

This is the continuation of my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/708437/1855).

I added frame number and total frame in every slide, but I would like to skip and remove both frame and total frame numbers in title page and section page. THow can I achieve that?

Thank you in advance.

This is MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berkeley}

\AtBeginSection[]{
{
\hoffset=-.5\beamersidebarwidth
\begin{frame}[plain]
\vfill
\centering
\begin{beamercolorbox}            
[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
\usebeamerfont{title}\thesection. \insertsectionhead\par%
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vfill
\end{frame}
}
}


\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\footnotesize\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}}

\title{Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title }
\author{Author Author}

\begin{document}

{
\hoffset=-.5\beamersidebarwidth
\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle
\end{frame}
}

\section{Section 1 Section 1 Section 1 Section 1 }
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
    Frame 1
\end{frame}
\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
    Frame 2
\end{frame}
\subsection{Section 3 Section 3 Section 3 Section 3}
\begin{frame}{Frame 3}
    Frame 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE does not use the Berkley theme and thus does not even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- to skip certain frames during numbering, you can use the `noframenumbering` frame option
- you can use `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` to remove the navigation symbols on plain frames (or the frame numbers in your particular case). If you would prefer an automatic solution for all plain frames, see https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=2047#a2293

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berkeley}

\AtBeginSection[]{
{
\hoffset=-.5\beamersidebarwidth
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
\vfill
\centering
\begin{beamercolorbox}            
[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
\usebeamerfont{title}\thesection. \insertsectionhead\par%
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vfill
\end{frame}
}
}


\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\footnotesize\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}}

\title{Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title }
\author{Author Author}

\begin{document}

{
\hoffset=-.5\beamersidebarwidth
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
\maketitle
\end{frame}
}

\section{Section 1 Section 1 Section 1 Section 1 }
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
    Frame 1
\end{frame}
\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
    Frame 2
\end{frame}
\subsection{Section 3 Section 3 Section 3 Section 3}
\begin{frame}{Frame 3}
    Frame 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```